# Reading values from xml file with Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm having troubles reading values from an xml file.
Here is the xml file:

```
<root>
    <defaultGroups name="Sikker">
        <group name="0ASK" />
        <group name="0ASKAPP" />
        <group name="0ASKFELLES" />
        <group name="0SYSAPP" />
        <group name="0SYSAPPoffice" />
        <group name="10WTS" />
    </defaultGroups>
    <defaultGroups name="Intern">
        <group name="11WTS" />
        <group name="1ASK" />
        <group name="1ASKAPP" />
        <group name="1ASKFELLES" />
        <group name="Domain Users" />
        <group name="Askvoll brukere" />
        <group name="1SYSAPP" />
        <group name="1SYSAPPAdobeReader" />
        <group name="1SYSAPPEXCEL" />
        <group name="1SYSAPPIEXPLORER" />
        <group name="1SYSAPPOUTLOOK" />
        <group name="1SYSAPPPOWERPOINT" />
        <group name="1SYSAPPWORD" />
    </defaultGroups>
</root>
```

With the function shown below, I'm supposed to only read the values from `<defaultGroups name="Sikker">`. I do get the first value: "0ASK", but not the rest. Can someone please help me with this? (I'm new to Linq)

This is the C# function I use:

```
public string GetSikkerSoneDefaultGroups(string companyName)
    {
        string sikkerSone = "";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("xml\\defaults\\" + companyName + ".xml");
        var groups = from defaultGroups in doc.Descendants("defaultGroups")
                     where defaultGroups.Attribute("name").Value == "Sikker"
                     select new
                     {                             
                         g = defaultGroups.Element("group").Attribute("name").Value
                     };

        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            sikkerSone += group.g + ";";
        }

        doc = null;

        return sikkerSone;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using:

```
g = defaultGroups.Element("group").Attribute("name").Value
```

which only selects the first child element of defaultGroups.  I think we can simplify this quite a bit, as the way you're approaching it you would need a subquery.  Why not get the group elements directly?

```
var groups = from defaultGroup in doc.Descendants("group")
             where defaultGroup.Parent.Attribute("name").Value == "Sikker"
             select defaultGroup.Attribute("name").Value;


// Make it into a string
foreach (var group in groups)
{
     sikkerSone += group + ";";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much womp! This worked exactly as i wanted :)
Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

```
string sikkerSone = string.Join(";",
   (from dg in doc.Descendants("defaultGroups")
    where dg.Attribute("name") == "Sikker"
    from g in dg.Elements("group")
    select (string)g.Attribute("name"))
   .ToArray());
```