# Reading value from XML file into Textbox

Tags: c#, xml, file

I've been trying for days to read a value from XML file into a text box. I searched relevant questions:

[Reading values from xml file with Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363745/reading-values-from-xml-file-with-linq)
[C# Reading from XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261853/c-sharp-reading-from-xml-files)
[Getting values from xml file using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207811/getting-values-from-xml-file-using-c-sharp)
[How to Read values from XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013936/how-to-read-values-from-xml-file)
and videos:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4dPWkEARptI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DwANN5_BoE

Still, I couldn't correctly read the "Background" value and always get this Error:
(I doubt it has to do with hierarchy of the XML file and I'm not choosing the correct Element \ Node) What did I miss?

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
Additional information: 'None' is an invalid XmlNodeType.
```

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfXMLSaveClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <XMLSaveClass>

    <Background>D:\Temp\100 Ideas for Every Occasion.pdf</Background>

</XMLSaveClass>
```

My code so far:

```
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog OP = new OpenFileDialog();
            OP.Filter = "XML files (*.xml)|*.xml";
            OP.DefaultExt = "xml";
            OP.AddExtension = true;
            if (OP.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                XmlReader XDoc = XmlReader.Create(OP.Filename);

                while (XDoc.Read());
                {
                    if (XDoc.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && XDoc.Name == "Background")
                    {

                    }                   
                } 
                string L01 = XDoc.ReadElementString();
                txtInputFileT.Text = L01;   
            }
        }
```

Comment: To begin with, the XML snippet you've posted is incomplete.

Comment: @aybe could you please elaborate ?

Comment: It's not "incomplete", it's invalid XML.

Comment: @IanKemp which line is invalid ?

Comment: the tag `ArrayOfXMLSaveClass` has no closing tag. Anyway why do you parse the xml yourself node by node? Why not use `linq2Xml` or an `XmlSerializer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the following, it does read and print all `Background` descendants ?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace zzzzzzzz
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<ArrayOfXMLSaveClass xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
  <XMLSaveClass>
    <Background>D:\Temp\100 Ideas for Every Occasion.pdf</Background>
  </XMLSaveClass>
</ArrayOfXMLSaveClass>
";

            using var reader = new StringReader(xml);

            var xDocument = XDocument.Load(reader);

            var xElements = xDocument.Descendants("Background");

            foreach (var element in xElements)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{element.Name}: {element.Value}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

This works, by the way, your XML wasn't valid, here's a correct one:

[image]

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dialog = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                Filter = "XML (*.xml)|*.xml"
            };

            if (dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
                return;

            using var stream = dialog.OpenFile();
            using var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element || reader.Name != "Background")
                    continue;

                var value = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

                MessageBox.Show(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ArrayOfXMLSaveClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <XMLSaveClass>
        <Background>D:\Temp\100 Ideas for Every Occasion.pdf</Background>
    </XMLSaveClass>
</ArrayOfXMLSaveClass>
```

Comment: the code in my question, worked in some of the example videos, however it does not on my end. Could you pin point the cause? Much appreciate it.

Comment: works perfectly with only 1 line in XML file. When I add more Elements it gives an error and goes to line 59 which the last line in he file `The ReadElementContentAsString method is not supported on node type None. Line 59, position 23.`

Comment: use XDocument, it's much better